# Aliasing jar target of maven_jar rule

Tags: bazel

I have the following maven_jar in my workspace:

```
maven_jar(
    name = "com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305",
    artifact = "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1",
    sha1 = "f7be08ec23c21485b9b5a1cf1654c2ec8c58168d",
)
```

In my project I reference it through `@com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305//jar`. However, I now want to depend on a third party library that references `@com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305` without the jar target.

I tried looking into both `bind` and `alias`, however `alias` cannot be applied inside the WORKSPACE and `bind` doesn't seem to allow you to define targets as external repositories.

I could rename the version I use so it doesn't conflict, but that feels like the wrong solution.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1952

Comment: What rule kind and attribute is it in the third party library rule? I can depend on a `@com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305//jar` from a `java_library.deps` but not on `@com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305`.

Comment: I didn't mention in the original question because I was hoping for a general solution to the problem. It's the java_import_external rule in rules_closure (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/blob/master/closure/repositories.bzl#L277). It downloads a jar and exposes it as a java_import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, your code needs to depend on both `@com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305//jar` and `@com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305//:com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305`. Unfortunately, there isn't any pre-built rule that generates BUILD files for both of those targets, so you basically have to define the BUILD files yourself.  Fortunately, @jart has written most of it for you in [the closure rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/blob/master/closure/private/java_import_external.bzl) you linked to.  You just need to add `//jar:jar` by appending a couple of lines, after [line 69](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/blob/ec29b1685da171735b946388f836de75cd8371b8/closure/private/java_import_external.bzl#L69) add something like:

```
repository_ctx.file(
    'jar/BUILD', 
    "\n".join([
       "package(default_visibility = '//visibility:public')"] + _make_java_import('jar', '//:com_google_code_findbugs_jsr305.jar')
```

This creates a `//jar:jar` (or equivalently, `//jar`) target in the repository.